# Is there a bug in xpathSApply if you produce your own XML object?

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I tried the following:

```
library(XML)
top = newXMLNode("A")
newXMLNode("b", attrs=c(x=1,y='abc'),parent=top) 
newXMLNode("c", "With some text", parent=top)
top
xpathSApply(top,'//A/b/@x')
```

and the R stops working.

Comment: I attempt to save the XML into a file and parse it again and the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. Note that , this works fine:

```
xpathSApply(top,'//A/b') ## without attribute
```

As a workaround, you can get the attribute using `xmlGetAttr`:

```
xpathSApply(top,"//A/b",xmlGetAttr,"x")
```